# Used by another process - StreamReader/Writer

Tags: c#

I have a save and a load function.  When I click 'save' on my form I get a 'The process cannot access the file 'blah blah' because it is being used by another process'.

Here is my code for save and load functions -

Load -

```
public bool Load()
{
    string currentLine;
    string[] tokenisedLine;
    StreamReader reader;
    bool success = false; ;

    reader = new StreamReader("Appointments.txt");

    try
    {
        while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            tokenisedLine = currentLine.Split(' ');

            DateTime appointmentStartTime = DateTime.Parse(tokenisedLine[0]);
            int appointmentLength = int.Parse(tokenisedLine[1]);
            string displayableDescription = tokenisedLine[2];
            string location = tokenisedLine[3];

            appointments.Add(new Appointment(appointmentStartTime, appointmentLength, displayableDescription, location));

        }
        reader.Close();
        success = true;
    }

    catch(Exception)
    {
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Save -

```
public bool Save()
{
    string appointStart;
    string appointLength;
    string appointDescription;
    string appointLocation;
    bool success = false;

    StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter("Appointments.txt");
    try
    {   // Take appointments out of list and assign their properties to variables
        foreach (Appointment appointment in appointments)
        {
            appointStart = appointment.Start.ToString();
            appointLength = appointment.Length.ToString();
            appointDescription = appointment.DisplayableDescription;
            appointLocation = appointment.Location;

            //put variable strings on one line.
            string outputLine = appointStart + "    "+ appointLength + "    "+ appointDescription + "   " + appointLocation; ;

            // Write line to a txt file and put cursur on a new lne.
            outputFile.WriteLine(outputLine);
        }
        outputFile.Close();
        //Close the txt file and return true

        success = true;
    }
        //if unsuccessful catch the exception and return true
    catch(Exception)
    {
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: You should really wrap your streamwriter and streamreader in `using()`

Comment: The error message seems rather self explanatory.  Another process has a lock on the file you're trying to access.

Comment: begin by putting the `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` in a `using` block. I.E. `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName)) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use `using()` block for your StreamReader/StreamWriter. Otherwise you can  always close your object occurs or not an error

```
try{
  /*...*/
}catch(Exception){
  /*...*/
}finally{
   outputFile.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is really no other process accessing the file, it is most likely because of how you wrote your code. When an exception is thrown in either one of your examples, the `StreamReader` will not be closed and will therefor keep accessing the file.

To solve your problem you could either add a `finally` block or put your `StreamReader` into a `using` statement.

With finally:

```
public bool Load()
{
    string currentLine;
    string[] tokenisedLine;
    StreamReader reader;
    bool success = false; ;

    reader = new StreamReader("Appointments.txt");

    try
    {
        while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            tokenisedLine = currentLine.Split(' ');

            DateTime appointmentStartTime = DateTime.Parse(tokenisedLine[0]);
            int appointmentLength = int.Parse(tokenisedLine[1]);
            string displayableDescription = tokenisedLine[2];
            string location = tokenisedLine[3];

            appointments.Add(new Appointment(appointmentStartTime, appointmentLength, displayableDescription, location));

        }
        success = true;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        success = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Close();
    }
    return success;
}
```

With using:

```
public bool Load()
{
    string currentLine;
    string[] tokenisedLine;
    bool success = false; ;

    using(var reader = new StreamReader("Appointments.txt"))
    {
        try
        {
            while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                tokenisedLine = currentLine.Split(' ');

                DateTime appointmentStartTime = DateTime.Parse(tokenisedLine[0]);
                int appointmentLength = int.Parse(tokenisedLine[1]);
                string displayableDescription = tokenisedLine[2];
                string location = tokenisedLine[3];

                appointments.Add(new Appointment(appointmentStartTime, appointmentLength, displayableDescription, location));

            }
            reader.Close();
            success = true;
        }

        catch(Exception)
        {
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

I have just done the `Save` method, but the `Load` method needs to be done too.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked.  I have a different problem now.  Every time I save, whatever is in the txt file is overwritten.My load function doesn't seem to work either

Comment: `var reader = new StreamWriter("Appointments.txt", true)`. The second parameter tells the `StreamWriter` if it should append.

Comment: Should that go for the writer as well?

Comment: My fault. It is `StreamWriter` not the `StreamReader`

Comment: No probs.  Thank you for your help.  My load function does not seem to work though so something is amiss with the reading

Comment: I think this will help: `Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`. Although you should change the character on which you are splitting because if `appointment.DisplayableDescription` (or any other variable you are writing into the file) contains a space your format will break.

Comment: I get this error - Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions' to 'char' when I type this -  tokenisedLine = currentLine.Split('|', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Comment: Forgot that the first parameter was a `char[]`not a `char`. This should work: `currentLine.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`.

Comment: Maybe it is not there... ?